# Fast prime numbers between range

Tags: c#

I am trying to develop one program for develop very fast prime numbers. Prime numbers are to be generated in range (Range <= 10000) and the result should be printed in under 6 seconds. This is the program i have made so far. It runs just fine on my machine 1.73 core 2 duo and produces result in under 3 seconds. But when i submit it to online program submission validator it gives time limit exceeded. I have even removed try catch block etc as i thought removing try catch may save few resources and buy me few milliseconds, but no matter whatever i do i always get time limit exceeded. This is my code :-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace PrimeNumberGenerator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                int T = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                List<string> listInput = new List<string>();

                for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
                    listInput.Add(Console.ReadLine());

                for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
                {
                    string[] str = listInput[i].Split(' ');
                    int M = Convert.ToInt32(str[0]);
                    int N = Convert.ToInt32(str[1]);

                    if ((N - M) <= 100000 && M >= 1 && M <= 1000000000 && N >= 1 && N <= 1000000000)
                    {
                        int[] list = Enumerable.Range(M, (N - M + 1)).ToArray();
                        int k = 2;
                        while (true)
                        {
                            if ((k * k) > N)
                                break;
                            for(int j = 0 ; j < list.Count() ;j++)
                            {
                                if (list[j] != k && (list[j] % k) == 0 && list[j] != 1 && list[j] != -1)
                                    list[j] = -1;
                            }

                            k++;
                        }

                        foreach (int item in list)
                        {
                            if (item != -1)
                                Console.WriteLine(item);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Limit exceeded");
                }

        }
    }
}
```

You have to give input like this :-

1

2 30

1 is no of test case and 2 and 30 mean that all primes between 2 and 30 should be produced.
You can give it 1 if you are only testing it once. I will be very grateful if you can optimise this program

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT :-

This is the original implmentation that i thought but obviously has overhead of list :-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace PrimeNumberGenerator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                int T = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                List<string> listInput = new List<string>();

                for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
                    listInput.Add(Console.ReadLine());

                for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
                {
                    string[] str = listInput[i].Split(' ');
                    int M = Convert.ToInt32(str[0]);
                    int N = Convert.ToInt32(str[1]);

                    List<int> list = null;
                    if ((N - M) <= 100000 && M >= 1 && M <= 1000000000 && N >= 1 && N <= 1000000000)
                    {
                        list = Enumerable.Range(M, (N - M + 1)).ToList();
                        int k = 2;
                        while (true)
                        {
                            if ((k * k) > N)
                                break;
                            List<int> tempList = new List<int>();
                            foreach (int item in list)
                                if (item != k && (item % k) == 0 && item != 1)
                                    tempList.Add(item);
                            list = list.Except(tempList).ToList();
                            k++;
                        }

                        //list.Remove(1);
                        foreach (int item in list)
                            Console.WriteLine(item);
                        Console.WriteLine();

                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Limit exceeded");
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason for using C#?

Comment: Is the validator going to give any input or just run it?

Comment: The wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test has a few optimizations that would be easy to do.  For example, don't bother testing the even numbers.  (Or iterating through them... k=k+2).  For such a small range, a sieve might be more efficient... but probably not in C#.

Comment: @Neo :- No not any particular reason. It's just that currently only c# compiler is available on my laptop ;)

Comment: Writing(and reading) from console is a slow i/o process. Instead of using for loops for them, create a list and write using just one WriteLine command.

Comment: D'oh!  And a massive one... Are you given more than one input line?  Then don't bother testing primes you've already tested for.  And... and... Okay, I have to stop doing your homework now.

Comment: have you tried running it at a smaller range and making sure that time is not exceeded?  I strongly doubt that within 10k on any machine it would take long

Comment: @clintp :- What do you mean by a sieve might be more efficient... but probably not in C#? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Firoso :- Thanks i too wanted to ask same question.

Comment: @Gnostus :- I don't know and i am even not sure whether it is trusthworthy or not. I just give source code and it keeps showing progress bar and at the end shows time limit exceeeded.

Comment: sorry that people seem to think so, but C# is a fine language for nearly all practical development cases (except perhaps bleeding edge gaming)

Comment: @Firoso :- Is that your guess or you really have any proof of it? Microsoft as i know has C# as it's prime language and Xbox 360 games are made in c# and even Kinect games (XNA framework). I don't know what exactly you talking about!

Comment: @firoso,@kar - I was weighing C# vs C/C++. .NET framework involves compiling c# to CIL and then finally through CLR to runtime binary. This costs additional overhead, which should be avoided in a time-critical process.

Comment: I don't know that it would be possible to implement something like a very fast Sieve of Atkin in C# at the speeds that an unmanaged environment like C or assembler would offer.  Finish your homework, and then write some benchmarks.  :)

Comment: @clintp :- If you `don't know` it is better to be quiet :)

Comment: @Kar Cheng, only XNA games use C#, i'm just saying that C# has a higher level of abstraction, and although it can be VERY fast, micro-optimization can be tough :-P.

Comment: @Neo  This is true, but it's only initial overhead, which for most situations is negligable.

Comment: @Firoso : Just-in-time compilation methodology will always cause overheads that will slow the process at runtime. So unless you are using ahead-of-time compiling, which isn't the most popular method, there will be a significant performance difference between C# and C.

Comment: @Firoso :- Yes and XNA are the top selling of all. Kinect has broken Playstation market :p.

Comment: @Kar Cheng : I'm simply saying you're not likely to write unreal engine 4 in XNA :-P

Comment: @Neo your statement is true except for one word: "significant"  This was the first reference i could find, and it's obviously a bit "corner case"  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSharpVsCPP.aspx  But my point is, in practice there is very little difference.

Comment: @Firoso :- And why would i bother to write :p ? Writing top selling games should be my (actually anybody's) aim.

Answer (score 4):

All I can say is that looks like a lot of loops within loops you've got going on. Probably the main issue is just your general algorithm.

To test if a number is prime, it's sufficient to check whether it's evenly divisible by any number between 2 and its sqrt (rounded down).

But if you're checking many primes, you ought to leverage the fact that as you check higher and higher numbers you can start with only primes (I would store these in a simple `List<int>`). For example, say you've reached the number 27. You only need to check whether it's divisible by 2, 3, or 5 (the prime numbers you've already found less than sqrt(25) which is 5), not 4 (since 4 is divisible by 2—if it's divisible by 4, then it's divisible by 2), and not anything above that (if it's evenly divisible by anything above 5, the quotient will be below 5, and you would have already checked it).

Those are some general concepts that ought to help you optimize what looks upon first glance like a pretty inefficient algorithm.

Comment: - I originally did that only. You can checkout my original solution but in that also i am getting the same time limit exceeded.

Comment: @Kar Cheng: What's the website, out of curiosity? (Or is it not public?)

Answer (score 2):

There are three solutions to performance problems: benchmarks, benchmarks, benchmarks.

Use a profiler to benchmark your code. For C# I personally prefer [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) but there are also other options available.

I suggest you to update (or post another) your question with specific bottlenecks.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is expected to output the numbers in 6 seconds(time-critical), so you should make full use of the memory in the 6 seconds to save time. For example, you can use multi-threading or parallel programming to generate numbers faster(more CPU/memory usages). Currently you are working in a *regular* way, which can't show off C#'s advantages(your code can be converted directly into C/Java/others with few changes). You need to do it in the C# way, otherwise why do you choose C#? Here is an example<strike>(non-tested, but I think it should be correct)</strike> which is much more in C# way.

```
int min = 2;
int max = 10000;

Enumerable.Range(min, max - min + 1)
          .AsParallel()
          .ForAll(g =>
             {
                 bool prime = true;
                 for (int i = 2; i <= Math.Sqrt(g); i++)
                 {
                      if (g % i == 0)
                      {
                         prime = false;
                         break;
                      }
                 }
                 if (prime) Console.WriteLine(g);
             });
```

EDIT: I just tested the code, primes less than 10000 are printed out in 0 seconds, measured by `StopWatch`.

Comment: Your solution is indeed very good and easy. However they are using some old compiler and so 4.0 features may not be supported. I get this :- Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings /sources/tested.cs(34,12): error CS1061: Type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for `AsParallel' and no extension method `AsParallel' of type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) However i have voted for you. Learnt something new.

Comment: @Kar Cheng: Actually I'm not providing you a submitable program. Just want to tell you that since you choose C# as the programming language, you should use its *distinguishing feature*.